# Let $\dim(V)=n$. Given $v \in V$, $v \neq 0$, show that there is a basis ${v_1, \dots, v_n}$ for $V$ such that $v=v_1+\cdots+v_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\dim(V)=n$. Given $v \in V$, $v \neq 0$, show that there is a basis ${v_1, \dots, v_n}$ for $V$ such that $v=v_1+\cdots+v_n$.

I'm trying to do it using induction. I tried with $n=0$, but that is awkward, so I also do it for $n=1$

Suppose $n=0$, then $V=\emptyset$, so the basis is also $\emptyset$, and so $\emptyset=\emptyset$.

Suppose $n=1$.  Then $V=span({v_1})$ for some vector $v_1$. Then if we choose $v \in V$, then we have $v=c*v_1$ for some $c \in \mathbb R$. and $c*v_1$ is a new basis for $V$, so it holds for $n=1$

Suppose it hold for all values less than $k$. Let us prove it for $k$.
Choose a vector $v \in V$.

Now, this is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to prove that it is the sum of the vectors of a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend $\{v\}$ to a basis $\{v,v_1,\cdots ,v_{n-1}\}$ let $v_n=v-v_1-v_2-\cdots -v_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $v \neq 0$. Take any basis $B = \{b_1,...,b_n\}$ of $V$, there will exist some $b_k\in B$, such that $v = \lambda_1 b_k + ... + \lambda_k b_k + ... + \lambda_n b_n$ and $\lambda_k\neq 0$ (there will exist some coordinate in this basis that is nonzero).

Now take $v' = v - \lambda_k b_k$. Then by induction, there exists a basis $B'$ of $V' = Span(B \backslash\{b_k\})$ ($n-1$-dimensional vector space), such that $v' = \sum\limits_{b'\in B'} b'$.

Then $B'\cup\{\lambda_k b_k\} = B''$ is a basis of $V$ and $v = v' + \lambda_k b_k = \sum\limits_{b'\in B'}b' + \lambda_k b_k = \sum\limits_{b''\in B''}b''$.

Another case you have to take care of is when $v' = 0$, this can happen when only one coordinate is non-zero. Then by induction you get a basis such that n-1 coordinates are 1, and the last one is zero, and then you proceed as above.